# Credentials for link to google sheets not working in replit but working in idle python

Tags: python, google-sheets, replit

```
class GoogleSheets():
    
    def __init__(self,color,sheet_name,StartRowIndex,EndRowIndex,StartColumnIndex):
        self.color = color
        self.sheet_name = sheet_name
        self.StartRowIndex = StartRowIndex
        self.EndRowIndex = EndRowIndex
        self.StartColumnIndex = StartColumnIndex
        session = requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(connect=3,backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        session.mount('http://',adapter)
        session.mount('https://',adapter)
        self.file = "nea-project-395311-334f9063e146.json"
        self.sa = gspread.service_account(filename=self.file)
        self.sh = self.sa.open('Part of NEA Project')
        self.wks = self.sh.worksheet('Sheet1')
        self.scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
        self.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(self.file, self.scope)
        self.service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=self.credentials)
        self.spreadsheet_ID = "1PCYPD-uY5DGtHUtNi77uNN08u8dv5moiLeAZY8U7RF0"
        self.sheet_ID = 0
```

Obviously it's part of a much bigger code but this code specifically this line:

```
self.service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=self.credentials)
```

works in idle python but throws an error in replit. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Display.py", line 1593, in <module>
    Call_Functions()
  File "Display.py", line 1579, in Call_Functions
    Chart1 = GoogleSheets('blue','Rep weight against reps',2,146,5)
  File "Display.py", line 1102, in __init__
    self.service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=self.credentials)
  File "/home/runner/Project-file/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Project-file/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 287, in build
    content = _retrieve_discovery_doc(
  File "/home/runner/Project-file/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 404, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    raise UnknownApiNameOrVersion(
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: sheets  version: v4
```

I'm not sure why it's not recognising the sheets version v4. I've already tried to change it to v3 but has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://ask.replit.com/t/python-google-api-error-googleapiclient-errors-unknownapinameorversion-name-customsearch-version-v1/19255) from replit's forums might be relevant. Try modifying this part of your code:

```
self.service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=self.credentials)
```

to:

```
self.service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=self.credentials, static_discovery=False)
```

In addition, ensure that the following library is added to your code:

```
from apiclient import discovery
```

Comment: thanx i will try that tmwr and report back how it went

Comment: perfect it worked thanx. can u explain why it worked ?? please?

Comment: I believe this is most likely due to the fact that the static discovery document of Sheets V4 API is currently not part of the Python client library and would have to be fetched over the internet. Unless otherwise specified, `static_discovery` is set to true which results in replit throwing an `UnknownApiNameOrVersion` error since it cannot find the static discovery doc in its library. Feel free to let me know if you have any additiona questions or accept/upvote the answer if it has been useful.

Comment: like what is the static discovery document of the sheets v4 api. like ik how to implement the set up for google sheets but dunno exactly what the build,service,credentials,batch request and eerything does exactly. ik the syntax but if you could explain the logic just to complete my knowledge i would be extremely grateful

Comment: The discovery document is available [here](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis). However, I'm not that well-versed with Python and I can't really identify why it's not included in the client library. I suggest posting another question regarding this as the discussion has shifted away from the primary inquiry of your original post. A new question would also allow more knowledgeable members of the community to contribute.

Comment: okay cool thanx u for helping me btw. I'm really grateful